# "Invalid argument" :Do I miss something?

Tags: node.js, sunos

I'm trying to install nodejs v6.16 from .tar.gz file, so after downloaded and uncompressed the file, I export some env path like this:

```
> export NODEJS_HOME=/usr/lib/nodejs/node-v6.16.0/bin export
> PATH=$NODEJS_HOME:$PATH
```

Then, try to run "node -v" and it still show "Invalid argument"

My System is "SunOS 11.3 sun4v sparc sun4v"

I haved already try to install with  pkgutils like this tip https://www.techrunnr.com/how-to-install-nodejs-in-solaris-server/ but it doesn't work.

Comment: export NODEJS_HOME=/usr/lib/nodejs/node-v6.16.0/bin export  --> export NODEJS_HOME=/usr/lib/nodejs/node-v6.16.0/bin

Comment: mmmhhh......? so what's different ?

Answer (score 0):

The variables need to be set on this way:

```
export NODEJS_HOME=/usr/lib/nodejs/node-v6.16.0
export PATH=$NODEJS_HOME/bin:$PATH
```